# running time of the algorithm

Tags: java, time

I am trying to figure out what is the running time of the following algorithm.

```
public static int displayOccu(int[] a, int n, int i)
{
    if(i == a.length)
        return 0;
    else if(a[i] == n)
        return 1+displayOcc(a,n,i+1);
    else
        return displayOcc(a,n,i+1);
}
```

I thought it would be the length of a but I don't know how to verify it! Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`O(n)` - you iterate the array only once: probably starting with `i=0` and move forward one index upon every recursive call, until the end of the array is reached.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String... args){

     long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

     //your method call here

     long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

     System.out.println("The algorithm took "+ (endTime-startTime)+" milliseconds");

}
```

Comment: What was the method call?